# The source file is different from when the module was built error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I currently have one solution that references ten .dll files.  Those .dll files in turn all reference a shared .dll file.

Today I started getting an error while debugging that stated, "The source file is different from when the module was built error.", immediately following a recompile of the shared .dll.

I tried all of the usual.  I deleted bin and object folders.  I recompiled.  I closed all instances of Visual Studio and restarted after they were all closed.  I restarted my machine.  Nothing fixed seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing one of your 10 DLLs references a different copy of the shared DLL, and not the one you compiled.

Since you have all the sources, put all the projects in the same solution, and have the DLLs reference the shared DLL's *project*. This will solve your problem.

Comment: All of the 10 dlls are supposed to reference the same .dll, but copy local is enabled and they are included in the output folder.  Even though all 11 solutions are referencing the one file that's supposed to be in the release folder, the file being pulled into the primary solution was coming from the output folders of one of the referenced .dlls.  Since that solution had not been updated, the new version of the shared .dll was not in that output folder.  During compilation, that reference was the first to reference that shared .dll, and the file in the output folder was copied instead.

Comment: I'm going to vote you up, since this probably also solves the problem.  I didn't, however, want to reference the entire project with all solutions.  I don't want it to be set up so that I can make a change in one solution that breaks another.  I want it to be set up so that older versions are independent and can continue working, at least temporarily until they can be updated.

Comment: It looks like I'll have to wait 7 hours to post the solution I used.  =)

Answer (score 1):

It has happened to me too.  Once I fixed it by recompiling project-by-project from ground up (in the same order that VS does).

Another time this didn't help.  I can't remember what I did then.

I believe it is a bug in VS.
I notice you are running VS2008.  The problem might go away with an upgrade (the supposed bug might have been fixed).  VS2010 is also nicer to work with than VS2008 so it could be areason of its own to stay current.  Why not download an evaluation VS11 and try it there.

Move all projects to one solution, reference them in a simple and correct way.  Compile.  Now you have the right DLLs everywhere and can go back to your more diverse solution(s).

You can also try to use MSBuild.  It is easy since you already have the projects in VS.  Once it is build by MSBuild (which VS uses itself) it should probably compile in VS again.

Finally you can try to build with nAnt.  Once it compiles you can probably compile in VS again.

Good luck.  I've been there.  It sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I **suppose** you referencing in your project directly to some DLL, and not a *project*. Which means if you even cleanup and rebuild, the *same* dll will be used like a reference.
Very often this is a problem, so I suggesting you check your references.

Answer (score 0):

[edit] Assumed this was asp.net, disregard. [/edit]

Have you deleted everything your temporary .NET folders?

Either in:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[Your Version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files

or

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64[Your Version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Comment: I did not have to do that in order to solve the problem.  The primary solution is a windows app.  The 10 referenced .dlls are class libraries.  The 10 referenced .dlls are referencing another class library.  I'm not sure if ASP.NET temp folders would be applicable in this scenario.

Comment: Ha.  I thought I was browsing the .NET tag.  My bad.  Check those 10 references to the shared .dll and make sure copy local isn't turned on.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing last-modified dates of the shared .dll across output folders of all of the solutions with the file that was stored in the output folder of the primary solution, I noticed that they were not the same as the file that I had just built.

This didn't make sense to me, so I simply copied the new files into the output folder.  This did NOT solve the problem.  On subsequent builds, the old version was again placed into the output folder, immediately causing the error while debugging...

During compilation, an older version was being pulled along with one of the other referenced .dlls.  There is obviously some sort of check that is made with the names of files pulled in so that only 1 file is used, but no check is made for latest version number.

**I was able to actually solve the problem by creating a reference to the shared .dll from the primary solution.**  Direct references are obviously (or perhaps hopefully) pulled in before files that are referenced by references (and are already copied into the same output folder as those referenced .dlls), so the latest file was successfully pulled in first.

If clarity is needed, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I rarely respond to posts since I am generally too busy, but I just spent a ton of time on this same exact problem.  I am running VS 2008 in Windows 7.  I had set the my Visual Studio to run in XP Compatibility Mode to fix some issues I had with a different project and forgot to reset it to NOT run in compatibility mode.

Once I removed the Run In compatibility MODE (In Windows Explorer on the DevEnv.exe) my problem with the source being out of sync with the debug information went away.

Hopefully this might help someone in the future with the same problem.